# Unable to compile pjsua binaries

Tags: c, xcode, macos, pjsip

I'm trying to compile and run a small c app I built using PJSua. When I try to run the app, I get tons of error, one of which is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_ASN1_INTEGER_get", referenced from:
  _get_cert_info in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ASN1_STRING_data", referenced from:
  _get_cert_info in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ASN1_STRING_length", referenced from:
  _get_cert_info in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8", referenced from:
  _get_cert_info in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
  _flush_write_bio in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_free", referenced from:
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_new", referenced from:
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_new_file", referenced from:
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_s_mem", referenced from:
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_BIO_write", referenced from:
  _asock_on_data_read in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_CRYPTO_free", referenced from:
  _get_cert_info in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_DH_free", referenced from:
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ERR_clear_error", referenced from:
  _reset_ssl_sock_state in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ERR_error_string_n", referenced from:
  _asock_on_connect_complete in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
"_ERR_get_error", referenced from:
  _ssl_write in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _asock_on_connect_complete in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _asock_on_data_read in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _pj_ssl_sock_renegotiate in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _do_handshake in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _on_handshake_complete in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  _create_ssl in libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  ...
```

I added the compiled lib files to the "Link Binary With Libraries" in xCode. I have:

- libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjlib-util-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjnath-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjsip-ua-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjsip-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjsip-simple-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- libpjsua-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0.a
- AudioToolbox.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- AVFoundation.framework

Am I using the wrong lib files? There were tons of file in the lib folder when I ran the configure script with the prefix that included the output folder

Comment: please post a complete, minimal source that shows the problem.   Please post the compile statement.  Please post the link statement.  The posted question looks like the root of the problem is in the link statement.  When compiling, did you enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings?

Comment: There were no warnings. Just those red errors. When I remove those files from the Link Binary With Libraries then I get significant less errors (like 200+ drop to 15). The remaining ones seem to have to do with PJSua itself (which would be a different question). Also, what do you mean by "link statement"? Oh and the "..." in that error is the actual end of it. Anything after seem to be another error

Comment: the application `pjsua` comes complete and is used to make calls, receive/answer calls, and perform `telnet` activities.  it is not a compiler/linker.  So, exactly what are you trying to perform?

Answer (score 0):

did you read the `README.txt` file?  it says exactly how to generate the executables.

Here is an extract from that file:

begin:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
```

This article describes how to download, customize, build, and use the open
   source PJSIP and PJMEDIA SIP and media stack. The online (and HTML) version
   of this file can be downloaded from http://www.pjsip.org/using.htm

Quick Info
     _________________________________________________________________

Building with GNU tools (Linux, *BSD, MacOS X, mingw, etc.)
          Generally these should be all that are needed to build the libraries,
          applications, and samples:

$ ./configure
   $ make dep && make clean && make

Building Win32 Target with Microsoft Visual Studio
          Generally we can just do these steps:

```
     1. Visual Studio 6: open pjproject.dsw workspace,
     2. Visual Studio 2005: open pjproject-vs8.sln solution,
     3. Create an empty pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h, and
     4. build the pjsua application.
```

Building for Windows Mobile
          Generally these are all that are needed:

```
     1. Open pjsip-apps/build/wince-evc4/wince_demos.vcw EVC4 workspace,
     2. Create an empty pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h, and
     3. build the pjsua_wince application.
```

end:

Notice there is nothing about using the `code blocks` ide.

Rather use the command line:

Note: the text about which tools are needed.  Mostly that means the `gcc` tool chain needs to be downloaded and installed.

I'm running linux 14.04.4.

In a terminal window I entered:

```
./configure
```

and when that finally finished I entered:

```
make dep && make clean && make
```

and when that finished, I now have the executables, etc at my disposal.

Suggest:

1. delete everything you have done so far with those source files
2. download a fresh copy from: `http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm`
3. follow the instructions this time.

Comment: Yes, did you not read my last sentence of the question? I already did all of that and I'm using xCode as I'm on a mac. Yes I followed the mac version of the documentation and got all of the binaries. Those are generated after running that configure script as it checks the machine you are using and creates those files

Comment: @yob-v-u,  then what are you doing that is different?  I downloaded and ran on ubuntu linux 14.04 with gcc and it compiled/linked/installed correctly.

Comment: That's the point of my question. I don't see any documentation about xcode. So I'm guessing maybe there's some configuration I'm missing in xcode. As like I mentioned, if I remove those binaries, than that kind of error doesn't appear.

Comment: the `gcc` utilities are free, versions are available for MAC-X OS, Suggest download/install `gcc` and its tool chain then bypass xcode when performing the compile/link/install of the library.